# Terraform : private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I configured a Github action with Terraform Cloud to run a plan. The same workflow worked with a blank state in Terraform, but when I imported my local state it started failing.
To import state, on my local environment, I followed these [instructions](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360061289934-How-to-Import-Resources-into-a-Remote-State-Managed-by-Terraform-Cloud) to import my local state to the remote state.
Basically, logging in with `terraform login`
adding

```
terraform {
  cloud {
      organization = "xxxx"
      workspaces {
        name = "prod"
      }
    }
}
```

to my main.tf, running `terraform init`, and then my import script. I can see the state populated in Terraform Cloud UI.

However, I'm getting

> Error: Error when reading or editing PubsubSchema "projects/xxxx-dev/schemas/user_email_schema": Get "https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxx-dev/schemas/user_email_schema?alt=json": private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:13 length:45 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue: tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} pkcs1PrivateKey @2

which looks like an authentication error. What's weird is that i get these errors for all resources of a specific kind, namely pubsub schemas. For other resources, terraform plan is able to run correctly.

This is how a schema is defined in the tf file

```
resource "google_pubsub_schema" "match_schema" {
  name = "match_schema"
  type = "AVRO"
  definition = file("${path.module}/schemas/match_schema.avsc")
}
```

The structure of the folder is

```
project-root/
│
├── infra/
│   └── schemas.tf  
│
└── schemas/
    └── match_schema.avsc
```

When looking at the state in Terraform UI, I can see each resource has a `private` key. The value is the same for ALL resources

Still in the UI, the schemas have a definition key, which hints at the file being read correctly. For the match_schema:

```
 "definition": "{\n \"type\" : \"record\",\n \"name\" : \"match\",\n \"fields\" : [\n   {\n     \"name\" : \"driver_uid\",\n     \"type\" : \"string\"\n   },\n   {\n     \"name\" : \"passenger_uid\",\n     \"type\" : \"string\"\n   },\n   {\n     \"name\" : \"id\",\n     \"type\" : \"string\"\n   }\n\n ]\n}",
```

It seems to correspond to my local file:

```
{
 "type" : "record",
 "name" : "match",
 "fields" : [
   {
     "name" : "driver_uid",
     "type" : "string"
   },
   {
     "name" : "passenger_uid",
     "type" : "string"
   },
   {
     "name" : "id",
     "type" : "string"
   }

 ]
}
```

Comment: Terraform errors usually show the resource and line number that is causing the error, can you share that section of your code

Comment: Hi, I added it in the main body of the question

Comment: I get a feeling that the `file(...path...)` might not be correct, can you add just an output on that then do a TF Plan to see if it outputs correctly

Comment: The filepaths are correct. I get `parameter: no file exists` otherwise